# Using git for organizing documents

Tags: git

I have the following task that I would like to solve with git:
given a "pool-branch" that contains a pool of documents, I have in mind to add new documents or updated ones to the pool-branch and then create "views" on that pool that contain "references" to subsets of the documents that meet certain criteria and also allow to retrieve these documents.

An example should make clear what I need:
suppose I collect all interesting documents about gardening and put them into the pool-branch and then I want to be able to retrieve all documents related to flowers and in a different collection all that are related to vegetables and yet another to fruits also if the related sets of documents are not disjoint.

> **Question:**
> how can references to subsets of the files in a "pool-branch" be kept in   "special-topic" branches in a way that allows for always retrieving their most recent version?

I don't want to categorize the documents in the pool-branch because the definition of categories may vary over time.

Comment: Git is a source control system, not a document/content management system. I don't see how a source control system fits your description of your task at all.

Answer (score 0):

GIT is meant for storing textual documents, usually source files of code, so that later on its possible to update / add new/ delete these source files. That's why its called "source control system". Based on your question, I hardly see how you can benefit from git.

Let me ask you:

- Are the documents binary or "clear text"?
- Will you update the existing documents and want to track the history of these updates?

If the answer is "no" even for one of them, then think again whether git is the right tool...

Anyways, for disjoint sets of documents you can use branch - one per set of documents. You can also utilize the "convention" so that your branches will look like:

`pool/flowers`, `pool/vegetables` (with slashes) so that you'll see all the branches by `git branch` command and will know where to switch. When you switch to a new branch, the filesystem content will change. You'll also have to handle the state of new "category" creation. So that if you have `pool/flowers` and want to add a new `pool/trees`, the checkout will bring the empty folder. Its possible to keep one "clean" branch and checkout from it.

Another approach is using only one git branch, but keep the documents in the different folders. This is what programmers really do.
With this approach, you'll end up with the filesystem that looks like this:

```
pool
  |___ flowers
  |          |____ tulip.txt
  |          |____ rose.txt
  |          ....
  |___ trees
             |____ oak.txt
             |____ mapple.txt      
             ....
```

The "disjoint" sets will be just taking the content of the folder.
Again, in this case I don't really see any benefits of using git (maybe you should clarify in the question this point to get better answers).

Comment: so there is no git workflow for the equivalent situation in which I have a branch Utils that contains tons of files and a development branch that requires only a very small subset of the utility files that upon $git rebase Utils extracts the latest version from Utils without cluttering the local directory with unused files; if that is actually the case, then git's flexibility would be limited.

Comment: I just found this https://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/ that may point out where to to put the lever.

Comment: git annex https://git-annex.branchable.com/ also seems to fit my bill...